# TTK List View with Icons Frame/Canvas/Widget/Listbox/Whatever

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, ttk, ttkwidgets

I cant seem to figure out where I would start to make something like this:

[image: System32 Small Icon View]

I just want to have something to select pairs of text and icons like in windows explorer with "Small Icons" selected.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

title = "Select Sheets Items"

dlg = Tk()
```

Comment: That's an iconlist "megawidget" (widget made out of other widgets) and isn't in the public API because it isn't finished; there's just enough there to implement the file chooser dialogs on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TkTreeCtrl - https://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/ - can do stuff like this, e.g. https://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/pics/explorer4.png .  It does take some study to get into, but it's seriously powerful.

I've only used it from Tcl, but it appears you could use it from Python via https://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/ .